# How to iterate through members of a third party object in C# that is not available at compile time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms control which has a parent control that is third party.  I want to see what members it has.

`.GetType().Name` gives me the type (which is LayoutTable)

The problem is that LayoutTable does not exist at compile time as this is a dll which is loaded into a framework, so I need to do this at runtime.

If it were available at compile time I could do something like this:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(LayoutTable).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    ...
```

to get the properties, but how do I do this at runtime?

LayoutTable is based on Control as that is what I am using to get to it in the first place, so I would need to convert it to a LayoutTable before looping through its members.

Can somebody help me out here.

Comment: Well instead of `typeof(LayoutTable)` you use `foo.GetType()`... I'm not sure what you're missing here. It's important to understand the two bits of code you have: you already know how to get the type at execution time (call `GetType()`) and you already know how to get properties from a type (call `Type.GetProperties())`...

Comment: Cheers Jon - that works a treat

Comment: And how do I get the methods?

Comment: Well, what research did you do before asking? Hint: you call `GetProperties` to get the properties, so to get the methods you would call...?

Comment: ok - ha ha - cheers  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object myObj; //this can be anything
PropertyInfo[] properties = myObj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{ 
}
```

The rest remains the same - there is no need to convert it at all, as Reflection works on metadata (determination at runtime).

Comment: So will this also pick up the properties of the derived class or just the `object` class

Comment: all the properties of the given class, not just of object. PropertyInfo allows to inspect the DeclaringType (Property) to check the class it was defined..